# android - cannot access soap web service

Tags: android, web, service

I'm trying to create an android application which could be able to access a Web Service. 

I used the example provided on this website: http://codeoncloud.blogspot.fr/2013/06/android-java-soap-web-service-access.html (part 1).

However it doesn't work at all, it keeps displaying "1 USD = LKR" instead of "1 USD = 128.95 LKR". And yet, this code uses threads (because after much research, I found out that network requests need to be done on background thread after Android 3.0). 

I've also tried to create an AsyncTask but it doesn't work either.

Here is an example of my code below:

RetrieveFeedTask (my AsyncTask):

```
public class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>{
private Exception exception;
private static String webResponse = "";
protected void doInBackground(String NAMESPACE, String METHOD_NAME, String fromCurrency, String toCurrency, String SOAP_ACTION, String URL) {
    try {
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
         PropertyInfo fromProp =new PropertyInfo();
         fromProp.setName("FromCurrency");
         fromProp.setValue(fromCurrency);
         fromProp.setType(String.class);
         request.addProperty(fromProp);
         PropertyInfo toProp =new PropertyInfo();
         toProp.setName("ToCurrency");
         toProp.setValue(toCurrency);
         toProp.setType(String.class);
         request.addProperty(toProp);
         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         envelope.dotNet = true;
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
         androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
         SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
         setWebResponse(response.toString());
         } catch (Exception e) {
        this.exception = e;
        return;
    }
}
    protected void onPostExecute (Void feed) {
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
    public static String getWebResponse() {
    return webResponse;
}
    public void setWebResponse(String webResponse) {
    this.webResponse = webResponse;
}}
```

Do you have any clue why these both methods don't work despite the tutorials?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding the properties directly to request object using .addProperty("property",value). it looks correct though. I can't remember how offhand but you can turn on debugging, try that too.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you set transport debug to true? whats the dump?

Comment: Do you really have three `doInBackground()` methods in one AsyncTask? `doInBackground()` does only take one parameter. In your case String ...

Answer (score 0):

you can access soap web service with ksoap library.refer following url 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/consuming-web-services-with-ksoap--mobile-21242

Comment: Thanks but I've done it already. It's like I can't get any answer from the Web Service (despite the tutorials), but it maybe comes from my code.